# Find out from within a class if an event handler exists in another class

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling, .net-4.0

A VB.NET 4 question.

Let's assume there exists a class A which contains an event E. In another Class (B), a variable of type A is declared WithEvents. At a certain point withing A's code, there will be a "RaiseEvent E" command. After that, is there a way to know if E was handled within B (just if a handler of event E exists in Class B)?

Obviously E could contain a parameter (i.e. boolean) so that if a handler within B handles it, it could set this parameter to True. This is not what i'm asking though. I would like to know if there is a built-in-to-.NET way to achieve this, without the use of any parameters.

A code example of what i'm trying to avoid (the use of parameter DoSomethingWasHandled):

```
    Public Class A
        Public Event DoSomething(ByRef DoSomethingWasHandled As Boolean)
    
        Public Sub RaiseDoSomething()
            Dim DoSomethingWasHandled As Boolean = False
            RaiseEvent DoSomething(DoSomethingWasHandled)
        End Sub
    End Class
    
    Public Class B
        Public WithEvents SomeA As New A
    
        Private Sub HandleDoSomething(ByRef DoSomethingWasHandled As Boolean) Handles SomeA.DoSomething
            DoSomethingWasHandled = True
        End Sub
    End Class
```

A code example of what i'm asking if it exists:

```
    Public Class A
        Public Event DoSomething()
    
        Public Sub RaiseDoSomething()
            RaiseEvent DoSomething()
            If DoSomething.WasHandled Then '<-- Does this check exist in any form? ***
                DoSomethingElse()
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
    
    Public Class B
        Public WithEvents SomeA As New A
    
        Private Sub HandleDoSomething() Handles SomeA.DoSomething
            'DoStuff...
        End Sub
    End Class
```

*** This would just check if an event handler of E exists in class B and return True if it does, False if it doesn't.

Comment: If you work at a restaurant and someone places a to-go order and takes his/her food home with them, do you know if he/she has consumed it or placed it in his/her refrigerator for later consumption?

Comment: I think that would be a bad design. You are raising the event for a consumer to handle. You shouldn't know or care what the consumer of the event does. Do you have a real-world use case in mind?

Comment: @HardCode: I want to know if the user has handled a specific event and if not, perform some default actions.

Comment: @FaultyOverflow that's not a real-world use case, that's a theoretical one. If you can describe a use case in detail, it would help try to figure something out.

Comment: I think in theory, you can check for subscribers to events (probably more easily in C# where you have lower-level access to the delegate).  In practice, it's probably better to do something with a `ByRef` argument to get information back out.

Comment: @FaultyOverflow - see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```
Public Class A
    Public Event DoSomething(e As Object)

    Public Sub RaiseDoSomething()
        ' adding 'Event' to the variable name of
        '  the event allows it to be checked
        If DoSomethingEvent IsNot Nothing Then 'does the event have a subscriber(Event Handler)?
            'yes
            RaiseEvent DoSomething("TEST") 'because there is a handler this will be handled
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class B
    Public WithEvents SomeA As New A

    Private Sub HandleDoSomething(e As Object) Handles SomeA.DoSomething
        Debug.WriteLine("Do")
    End Sub
End Class
```

A test

```
    Dim FOOa As New A
    Dim fooB As New B

    FOOa.RaiseDoSomething()
    fooB.SomeA.RaiseDoSomething()
```

Comment: I have used your example to update my OP, in order to better visualize what i'm trying to avoid, and that is the use of parameter DoSomethingWasHandled.

I just wonder if .NET has something built-in in order for the developer to know if there exists a sub in Class B that "Handles SomeA.DoSomething".

Comment: @FaultyOverflow - I have updated my answer with the answer you are seeking I believe.

Comment: Nope, not exactly. Updated again the OP in order to reflect what i'm asking for.

Comment: @FaultyOverflow - WHAT?  You might take a minute and rethink this.

Comment: I'd ask "why" here, but my final answer will be "never mind". I don't think it is supported anyway. In any case, thanks for sticking with it and tried to understand what i was asking.

Comment: @FaultyOverflow - Why? If you check for a handler and there IS one then the event IS handled when you raise the event. You seem to be hung up on checking AFTER you raise the event.

Comment: Well, the reason i would like to know if an event does not have a handler, is that if i try to check it with a parameter, the user (who may be other than me) may not set it. In that case, if the function that raised the event performs some default actions, there is a chance it will not be apparent to the user that the event should have been handled. I was basically thinking to write it to a log or perhaps raise it as as a warning within the IDE, so it would be easier to spot.